# как сделать возврат в owl карусели на первую позицию?

Tags: javascript, jquery

как сделать возврат в owl карусели на первую позицию ,когда при клике на меню нет следующего слайда на которое ссылается меню,а он предыдущий,но листать надо только дальше

Comment: Зависит от версии owl. Для 2.x достаточно в опциях поставить rewind:true

Comment: Мне по событию надо для owl второй

Comment: Там event-ы есть. owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [300]); - переместит на предыдущий слайд, owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [0, 400]); - на любую позицию(в данном случае на нулевую)

Comment: А можно вызвать тот метод который вызывается при безконечной прокрутки когда мы кликаем на следующий ,находясь в конце а перехдим на один из первых слайдов,зависит ,от количества,но не на первый ?

Comment: Не встречал таких. Проще наверное несколько раз next.owl.carousel вызвать.